# How to have JWT authentication between micro services in kubernetes cluster

Tags: java, authentication, kubernetes, jwt, microservices

We have 8 java microservices talking to each other in kubeneters cluster. Each microservice is bundled with auth library which intercepts and validates/renews JWT token for each REST request to controllers.

Scenario:
From Frontend, we get access token for the first time, Authentication gets successful. Lets say

1. Frontend hit 'Microservice A' with access token - Successful
2. 'Microservice A' internally hits 'Microservice B' via restTemplate.
   My 'Microservice B' also needs logged in user details.

Issue: I have to pass same access token from 'A' to 'B' but I am not able to get access token in Controller/Service logic but can get only in filters where token is being validated. I can get token in Rest Controllers by adding following argument in all rest methods in controller:

```
@RequestHeader (name="Authorization") String token
```

But I dont want to go with this approach as I have to pass this token to everywhere till end and have to declare this argument in all APIS.

I want to get token from TokenStore by passing authentication object. We are using Oauth2 and I checked the code in library, There are many tokenStore providers.

In DefaultTokenServices.java class, I am calling

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() // Passed this auth to tokenStore
String token = tokenStore.getAccessToken(auth).getValue(); // NullPointerException
```

My code is going through JWTTokenStore provider which is returning null. I checked, there is a provider called InMemoryTokenStore.class which actually extrActs token from store. But my flow is not going into in memory implementation.

Is there any way I can get token afterwards without grabbing it in controller via arguments? or how can I enable/use inMemoryTokenStore?

Also recommend something better for kubernetes intercommunication authentication?

TIA

Comment: You should probably look at `OAuth2RestTemplate`.

Comment: Essentially, you want an SPIFFE implementation to distribute tokens in your cluster, https://spiffe.io/

Comment: @Jonas, correct me if wrong, but my impression is that SPIFFE is only useful for service-level authN/Z, e.g. setting up a mTLS session. JWT, on the other hand, can be used for user- and/or resource-level authN/Z. Both are useful, but SPIFFE may not be a practical replacement for the JWTs mentioned in the Q if the OP is using keen on having a solution to authenticate users rather than just services.

Comment: @RoobalJindal What web framework are you using in your Java app?

Comment: @GrahamLea Spring security framework - Srpingboot

Comment: @RoobalJindal I thought so. Does the answer below help solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using Spring (and Spring Security), so I believe the relevant part of the docs is the part on [Bearer Token Propagation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#bearer-token-propagation).

Its recommendation is to use a `WebClient` (the recommended replacement for `RestTemplate` as of Spring 5) that uses the provided `ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction` to automagically propagate the JWT token from the incoming request into the outgoing request:

```
@Bean
public WebClient rest() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(new ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction())
            .build();
}
```

On `RestTemplate`, the docs say:

> "There is no dedicated support for RestTemplate at the moment, but you can achieve propagation quite simply with your own interceptor"

and the following example is provided:

```
@Bean
RestTemplate rest() {
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    rest.getInterceptors().add((request, body, execution) -> {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        }

        if (!(authentication.getCredentials() instanceof AbstractOAuth2Token)) {
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        }

        AbstractOAuth2Token token = (AbstractOAuth2Token) authentication.getCredentials();
        request.getHeaders().setBearerAuth(token.getTokenValue());
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    });
    return rest;
}
```

I don't believe you need to be looking at `TokenStore`s if all you're trying to do is propagate the token. Remember everything relevant about a JWT should be inside the token itself. (Which is why [the doc for the JwtTokenStore](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtTokenStore.html) explains that it doesn't actually store anything, but just pulls info out of the token, and will return null for some methods, including the `getAccessToken()` method you're calling.)